# Persist entities which own a relationship without getting the other side of the relationship first

Tags: java, jpa

Starting from a model in which an entity owns a relationship with other
entity. Second entity restricts the values that can be set on the property
which maps the relationship. Let me illustrate this better with an example.

```
+----------+
|   Box    |              +------------+
+----------+              |    BoxType |
|PK Box    |              +------------+
|FK BoxType|  * -----> 1  | PK BoxType |
+----------+              +------------+
```

These are the corresponding entities (in fact, real implementation differs
lightly from this example which I think keeps the necessary for me to show
what I want).

```java
@Entity @Table(name = "Box") public class Box {
  @Id @Column(name = "Box") private Integer box;
  @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(
    name = "BoxType",
    referencedColumnName = "BoxType"
  ) private BoxType boxType;
  // getters, setters
}

@Entity @Table(name = "BoxType") public class BoxType {
  public static enum BoxTypeEnum {
    SMALL, AVERAGE, BIG;
  }
  @Id @Column(name = "BoxType") private String boxType;
  public BoxTypeEnum getBoxType() {
    return BoxTypeEnum.valueOf(boxType);
  }
  public void setBoxType(BoxTypeEnum boxType) {
    this.boxType = boxType.name();
  }
}
```

Values `SMALL`, `AVERAGE` and `BIG` would already been saved in `BoxType`
table before application being run. Lets suppose  OpenJPA is used for
persistence provider. If there is a try to persist a Box instance an
exception is returned which shows `boxType` property holds an unmanaged
`BoxType` object.

```
<openjpa-2.3.0-nonfinal-1540826-r422266:1542644 nonfatal user error>
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException:
Encountered unmanaged object "BoxType@bdb3dc" in life cycle state
unmanaged while cascading persistence via field "Box.boxType" during
flush. However, this field does not allow cascade persist. You cannot
flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to
unmanaged objects.
Suggested actions:

  a) Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or
  CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA
  orm.xml),
  b) enable cascade-persist globally,
  c) manually persist the related field value prior to flushing.
  d) if the reference belongs to another context, allow reference to it
  by setting StoreContext.setAllowReferenceToSiblingContext().
```

If the relationship is marked as cascaded, on the contrary, an exception is
returned which shows the `BoxType` instance the application is trying to
persist already exists on the database.

```java
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(
  name = "BoxType",
  referencedColumnName = "BoxType",
  cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST
) private BoxType boxType;
```

The exception.

```
<openjpa-2.3.0-nonfinal-1540826-r422266:1542644 nonfatal store error>
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException:
An object of type "BoxType" with oid "SMALL" already exists in this
context; another cannot be persisted.
```

As far as I now I have two options:

1. Get a managed `BoxType` and update the reference on `Box`. This option
   requires an extra query on the database.

```java
box.setBoxType(entityManager.find(
  BoxType.class, box.getBoxType().getBoxType().name()))
entityManager.persist(box);
```

2. Use JDBC and SQL to insert the new register in the database.

```java
PeparedStatement preparedStatement =
  connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO Box(Box, BoxType) VALUES (?, ?);");
preparedStatement.setInt(1, box.getBox());
preparedStatement.setString(2, box.getBoxType().getBoxType().name());
preparedStatement.execute();
```

At the moment I've always implemented first option, besides it's
inefficient. I always mark BoxType-like entities as `@Cacheable` hopping it
will prevent the application to make the extra query.

My question is: ¿is there a way to persist the entity using JPA without
getting the other side of the relationship?, ¿are there any other ways to
persist an entity in these circumstances?, ¿does `@Cacheable` really prevent
the extra query?, ¿am I missing something?

There are related questions on StackOverflow ([this
one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781552/how-to-make-openjpa-2-2-0-not-persist-foreign-key)
is a good example) but none of them seems to focus on the same matter.

---

#### EDIT:

I confirm caching `BoxType` prevents the additional `SELECT` query. I've
annotated `BoxType` with `@Cacheable(true)` and added
`<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>` to the
persistence unit. Next I post a log section which shows the first time a
`Box` of some type is persisted the corresponding `BoxType` instance is
merged, while the second time only an `INSERT` is executed.

```
84485  boxPU  TRACE  [http-bio-8080-exec-3] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t
31743778, conn 30174353> executing prepstmnt 604724 
SELECT t0.BOX_TYPE 
    FROM BOX_TYPE t0 
    WHERE t0.BOX_TYPE = ? 
[params=?]
84765  boxPU  TRACE  [http-bio-8080-exec-3] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t
31743778, conn 30174353> [280 ms] spent
84846  boxPU  TRACE  [http-bio-8080-exec-3] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t
31743778, conn 30174353> executing prepstmnt 1210409 
INSERT INTO BOX (BOX, BOX_TYPE) 
    VALUES (?, ?) 
[params=?, ?]
84874  boxPU  TRACE  [http-bio-8080-exec-3] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t
31743778, conn 30174353> [28 ms] spent
165033  boxPU  TRACE  [http-bio-8080-exec-5] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t
20406142, conn 3709916> executing prepstmnt 25081694 
INSERT INTO BOX (BOX, BOX_TYPE) 
    VALUES (?, ?) 
[params=?, ?]
165034  boxPU  TRACE  [http-bio-8080-exec-5] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t
20406142, conn 3709916> [1 ms] spent
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer to your issue, but may solve it nevertheless:

Do not use enums like entities. There is simply no added value in persisting the enum values in a table and using this table. You can simply use the enum itself. You can delete the `BoxType` class, leaving only the `BoxTypeEnum`, which you can then rename to `BoxType`. Your Box class would then look like this:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private BoxType boxType;
```

or without renaming:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private BoxTypeEnum boxType;
```

EDIT: If you want to keep your entities as they are, and be able to persist new Boxes, you will have to merge the `BoxType` instance first and attach the merged instance to the box. Since it has it's `id` already set, the persistence provider assumes that it is an already persisted instance. This is why the persist cascade fails. You could probably fix it like this:

```
BoxType mergedAverageBoxType = em.merge(averageBoxType);  
box.setBoxType(mergedAverageBoxType);
em.persist(box);
```

However do think once again about the design of the `BoxType` class. If you want to make the list of box types extensible externally by mapping it to a table, do not use an `enum`, since you cannot have instances of `BoxType` with an `id` that is not listed in the `enum`.

If however you want to make the list of box types extensible only from the source code, the table is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @kostja. I've already considered using `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` myself. Maybe I'm doing things difficult but, ¿don't you think a constraint at database level may be useful?, maybe, if manual inserts or inserts from third party applications are allowed.

Comment: You're welcome :) A table OR an enum would make sense, but probably not both. Please see the edit.

Comment: I guess you're right @kostja, and for now I have no reason to make the list externally extensible so I'll use simply an `enum`. Thanks too for suggesting me to use `EntityManager.merge()`, I thought it was only used to update the database. However, I believe the underlying question remains unanswered. Merging `BoxType` requires in some cases the execution of a superfluous `SELECT` query, which is inefficient. Do you now how to persist a new `Box` without merging the `BoxType` instance?

Comment: You've got my point exactly right. So if you are aware of the consequences and are OK with them, don't let my reservations stop you :)